# Is it possible to wipe Windows 7 without using a CD or Flash drive?

Tags: windows-7, secure-erase

I am on a work contract for 1 week, during this time I've been assigned an old laptop which I installed Windows 7 on.

When the week is done I want to wipe the system, something like FDisk, really anything to ensure my personal data (any) is not left behind.

Is it possible to hit the kill switch in Windows, so that you can wipe the whole drive quick. I won't have time to do a reinstall. I just want the partition gone.

There is only 1 active partition, the boot C:\ drive.

Comment: Is there some technical reason why you can't use a boot disk of some sort? If you really want to be secure, you should use something like [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/), but that can take a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reboot your computer and hit F8.  On the Advanced Boot Options screen, use the arrow keys to highlight Repair your computer, and then press Enter.

You should be able to open a command prompt and launch FDisk from there.

Just know that fdisking your box isn't secure and there's a myriad of ways we can record data.

Edit: You can also launch a command line tool called BCDedit and blow away the boot configuration.  Also not very secure but it will make the machine non-bootable.